# How to set the default solver in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

The default solver in Dymola is DASSL, how could I change the default solver in Dymola environment?
Another question is :
If I want to set a default solver for a particular model, how could I use annotation to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to change the default solver in Dymola.

For a particular model you can either add the following annotation manually

```
 annotation (experiment(__Dymola_Algorithm="Radau"));
```

or use the UI, more specifically the simulation setup. The button "Store in Model" at the bottom left of the UI will generate the annotation shown above. Actually, having the flag next to it active, it should not even be necessary to click the "Store in Model" button.

[image: Dymola - Simulation Setup dialog]

Clicking "Store in Model" will open another dialog asking you which parts of the simulation setup shall be stored in the model. This refers to the tabs and should be self-explanatory.